# DART function, nested / inner functions variable

Tags: nested, dart, mailer, nested-function

I've the below code as anonymous function (also function literal or lambda abstraction), which is used in [DART mailer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mailer)

```
email(){ 
   ...
   emailTransport.send(envelope)
   .then((success) => print('Email sent! $success'))
   .catchError((e) => print('Error occured: $e'));
}
```

this worked fine, but I need to replace the "print" by a "return" to be like below:

```
email(){ 
   ...
   emailTransport.send(envelope)
   .then((success) => return 'Email sent! $success')
   .catchError((e) => return 'Error occured: $e');
}
```

but failed, the return had not been recognized!

I tried the below code, but failed too.

```
email(){ 
   ...
   var msg;
   ...
   emailTransport.send(envelope)
   .then((success) => msg = 'Email sent! $success')
   .catchError((e) => msg = 'Error occured: $e');

 return msg;
}
```

But the "msg" remained NULL!

any thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `return` in your function is not part of the chain of `Futures` that are executing your code. Your function is returning immediately; and the emailTransport.send method has not run yet.

Your function needs to return a Future; I don't think there is any way to "block" and wait for the result (and if there was, you probably wouldn't want to do this!).

You probably want to do something like this:

```
Future email() {
  ...
  return emailTransport.send(envelope)
   .then((success) => 'Email sent! $success')
   .catchError((e) => 'Error occured: $e');
}
```

And then, anything calling the function will need to also chain onto the future:

```
email()
  .then(msg => print(msg));
```

**Edit: based on comment**

The original method you're calling is asynchronous, so returns a `Future` (eg. something that will complete in the future). To do anything with this value, you need to "chain" more code onto the end (which as a result, will also return a `Future`, because it can't run until the first is completed).

You can assign to a variable inside a chained function, eg.

```
email().then((m) => msg = m);
```

However, this will only be executed once the async operation has completed, so it will not be immediately available after this line of code (this was ths mistake in your original code sample). If you want to do something with the value, you really need to chain that into the future too:

```
email()
  .then(doSomeOtherThing)

doSomeOtherThing(String msg) {
  // Do more processing here
}
```

If you're not familiar with Futures, there's an article on the Dart site that might be worth reading: [Use Future-Based APIs](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/)

It's very similar to how NodeJS works, nothing should ever "block", but instead, work that needs to be done after async/long-running work is effectively in a callback that gets tagged onto the end, and the runtime sits in a big loop processing what's next on the queue. There's a little more info on this here: [The Event Loop and Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/event-loop/).

Comment: Thanks, run perfectly, but what if I want to go further step and assign the returned output to a variable in the main function, I tried the following like returned_msg =  email().then((msg) => msg), the output msg appeared as "Instance of '_Future'"

Comment: @HasanAYousef I've edited a little more info onto my answer that hopefully will help. In short, you can't just block and wait for the result, you need to chain all dependent code onto the future.

Comment: Oh, it's probably also worth being aware that Dart is going to get an `await` keyword in the future, which will simplify this code, making it look synchronous (no chaining of .then(), it'll be rewritten to this automatically). This will work similarly to C#'s await (where `Future` in Dart is roughly equiv to `ask` in C#).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly, and exactly what I want. after reading the 2 pags you referred me to, I found another approach cool approach that could be useful in some cases, it is: email().then((msg) => mymsg= msg).then((_) {  /* Do more processing here   */ });

Comment: @HasanAYousef Glad it helped! FWIW, if you don't need the variable in the parent scope, `email().then((msg) => mymsg= msg).then((_) { /* Do more processing here */ });` is better just written as `email().then((msg) => /* Do more processing here */ });`. I extracted it into a separate function in my answer in case it was a lot of code :)

Comment: I tried further step, that I descried it [here] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410240/dart-server-to-send-future-function-output-back-to-the-client-how as this comment/reply space is not enough for that, can you help/comment pl. thanks