# DART server to send FUTURE function output back to the client, how?

Tags: dart, dart-async

In a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390297/dart-function-nested-inner-functions-variable/25391665) the server side dart file is calling a FUTURE email function that return either a confirmation msg or an error. the function below is working fine for the "print" function, but for the "res.write" is not working.

the server.dart file:

```dart
void handlePost(HttpRequest req) {
  HttpResponse res = req.response;
  print('${req.method}: ${req.uri.path}');
  addCorsHeaders(res);

  req.listen((List<int> buffer) {
    SendConfirmationNote2Client(String msg) {
      print('msg: $msg');     // this is working
      res.write(msg);         // this looks to be wrong!
      res.close();
    }
    email()
    .then(SendConfirmationNote2Client);
  }, onError: printError);
}
```

the client.dart file is:

```dart
void submitFprm(){   
  request = new HttpRequest();
  request.onReadyStateChange.listen(onData); 
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4040/'; 
  request.open('POST', url);
  request.send(JSON.encode(theData));
}  

void onData(_) {
  if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE && request.status == 200) {                               
    print('request.responseText');   // this is not printing anything!!
    server_output.innerHtml=request.responseText;  // this working  
  } else if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
    request.status == 0) {         
    print('no server');
  }
}
```

any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's the correct bug, but you have

```
print('request.responseText');
```

But this will print the literal text `request.responseText`. Should this instead be

```
print(request.responseText);
```

?

I would also try running Fiddler to see the exact response coming back from the server; in order to tell if the problem is with the server or client code.

Comment: :) I do not know how I did this mistake, you are correct, I just fixed it, also I was checking the server output in the DART editor, and once I wanted to check the client code output, I was looking the DART editor as will instead of refreshing the file URL, and checking the 'printing' output in the developer tool console.

Comment: @HasanAYousef Great; glad you figured it out :)